# No qualifying bean of type 'concert.PerformanceImp' available

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, aop, spring-aop

I am still a beginner in Spring Framework so I tried to code a program about "introduction" in Spring AOP but I am facing an error while compiling. Please find below the classes in the package `concert`:

> PerformanceImp.java

```
package concert;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PerformanceImp implements Performance {
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("This is the performance function");
    }
}
```

> Performance.java

```
package concert;

public interface Performance {
    public void perform();
}
```

> Encoreable.java

```
package concert;

public interface Encoreable {
    void performEncore();
}
```

> DefaultEncoreable.java

```
package concert;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DefaultEncoreable implements Encoreable {
    public void performEncore() {
        System.out.println("This is the performEncore function");
    }
}
```

> EncoreableIntroducer.java

```
package concert;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclareParents;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class EncoreableIntroducer {
    @DeclareParents(value="concert.Performance+",
            defaultImpl=DefaultEncoreable.class)
    public static Encoreable encoreable;
}
```

> ConcertConfig.java

```
package concert;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan("concert")
public class ConcertConfig {

}
```

And the main class:

> Main.java

```
package concert;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConcertConfig.class);
        PerformanceImp pi = (PerformanceImp) context.getBean(PerformanceImp.class);
        ((Encoreable) pi).performEncore();
        pi.perform();
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'concert.PerformanceImp' available
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the implementation (`PerformanceImp`) by default, because you enabled AOP, which sets to target interfaces instead of implementation. If you would remove `EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, you would see the code would work fine.

To understand a bit more about how AOP targeting works, take a look at this [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-proxies)

> Spring AOP can also use CGLIB proxies. This is necessary to proxy
>   classes rather than interfaces. CGLIB is used by default if a business
>   object does not implement an interface. As it is good practice to
>   program to interfaces rather than classes; business classes normally
>   will implement one or more business interfaces. It is possible to
>   force the use of CGLIB, in those (hopefully rare) cases where you need
>   to advise a method that is not declared on an interface, or where you
>   need to pass a proxied object to a method as a concrete type.

So you have two options:

1. Take the interface when trying to get the bean from the `ApplicationContext`.
2. Enable AOP to target concrete classes instead.

To do this point #2, modify your annotation as follows:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Performance pi = context.getBean("performanceImp", Performance.class);
```

instead of:

```
PerformanceImp pi = (PerformanceImp) context.getBean(PerformanceImp.class);
```

Comment: This works ! but why should I include the interface and not the implementated class.

Comment: Would you please explain more the difference between including the interface and not the class in the context ?

Comment: Spring creates beans when you specify the Config.class, and by default creates beans named with camel system. In this case it creates a bean named "perfomanceImp" which is a Performance interface implementation. That is why you can get that bean by its name and by specifying which interface it implements.

Comment: Not clear enough sorry. If Spring creates a bean named "performanceImp" why he cannot get the bean context.getBean(PerformanceImp.class); refering to his type

Comment: Actually when i run your code it works. I even used System.out.println(Arrays.asList(context.getBeanDefinitionNames())); to see which beans are created and it looks ok.