# Spring ApplicationContext.getBean returns wrong class

Tags: java, spring

I've been beating my head over this and I just can't figure out what's wrong.

I have a Spring app which uses ApplicationContext.getBean() to retrieve 2 similar classes. I'm getting the wrong instance class from the bean lookup.

Here's ApplicationContext class:

```
public class DomainRegistryCab {
    private static ApplicationContext           applicationContext;
 
    private static ApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( CaBridgeDomainServiceConfig.class );
    }   

    public static CertificateProductApplicationService certificateProductAppService() {
        var service = BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(
                applicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory(),
                CertificateProductApplicationService.class,
                CaBridgeDomainServiceConfig.CERTIFICATE_PRODUCT_APP_SERVICE);

//      var service = applicationContext().getBean(
//          CaBridgeDomainServiceConfig.CERTIFICATE_PRODUCT_APP_SERVICE,
//          CertificateProductApplicationService.class);
//      var service = applicationContext().getBean(CertificateProductApplicationService.class);
        validateDataSourceIs(DataSource.ProductDataStore, service.dataSource());
        return service;
    }

    public static CertificateProgramApplicationService certificateProgramAppService() {
        var service = BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(
                applicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory(),
                CertificateProgramApplicationService.class,
                CaBridgeDomainServiceConfig.CERTIFICATE_PROGRAM_APP_SERVICE);
//      var service = applicationContext().getBean(
//              CaBridgeDomainServiceConfig.CERTIFICATE_PROGRAM_APP_SERVICE,
//              CertificateProgramApplicationService.class);
//      service = applicationContext().getBean(CertificateProgramApplicationService.class);
        validateDataSourceIs(DataSource.ProgramDataStore, service.dataSource());
        return service;
    }
```

Here is CaBridgeDomainServiceConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { HibernateConfigurationMarker.class }) 
public class CaBridgeDomainServiceConfig {
    
    public static final String CERTIFICATE_PRODUCT_APP_SERVICE = "certificateProductAppService";
    public static final String CERTIFICATE_PROGRAM_APP_SERVICE = "certificateProgramAppService";
    
    @Bean(name= CERTIFICATE_PRODUCT_APP_SERVICE)
    public CertificateProductApplicationService certificateProductAppService() {
        return new CertificateProductApplicationServiceCabImpl();
    }

    @Bean(name= CERTIFICATE_PROGRAM_APP_SERVICE)
    public CertificateProgramApplicationService certificateProgramAppService() {
        return new CertificateProgramApplicationServiceCabImpl();
    }
}

public interface CertificateProductApplicationService extends CertificateApplicationService {
}
public interface CertificateProductApplicationService extends CertificateApplicationService {
}
public interface CertificateApplicationService {
}
```

Using the above classes if I call DomainRegistryCab.certificateProductAppService() I get an instance of CertificateProgramApplicationService not CertificateProductApplicationService.

I get similar results if I use this method:

```
public static CertificateProductApplicationService certificateProductAppService() {
    var service = applicationContext().getBean(
        CaBridgeDomainServiceConfig.CERTIFICATE_PRODUCT_APP_SERVICE,
        CertificateProductApplicationService.class);
    validateDataSourceIs(DataSource.ProductDataStore, service.dataSource());
    return service;
}
```

I've also tried having the @Bean methods return the implementation classes and the ApplicationContext().getBean() to request the implementation classes instead of the interfaces:

```
public class DomainRegistryCab {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
     
    private static ApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
    return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( CaBridgeDomainServiceConfig.class );
    }   
    
    public static CertificateProductApplicationService certificateProductAppService() {
    var service = applicationContext().getBean(CertificateProductApplicationServiceCabImpl.class);
        validateDataSourceIs(DataSource.ProductDataStore, service.dataSource());
        return service;
    }
    public static CertificateProgramApplicationService certificateProgramAppService() {
    var service = applicationContext().getBean(CertificateProgramApplicationServiceCabImpl.class);
        validateDataSourceIs(DataSource.ProgramDataStore, service.dataSource());
        return service;
    }
    public static ApplicationContext applicationContext() {
        if (applicationContext == null)
            applicationContext = createApplicationContext();
        return applicationContext;
    }
}

@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { HibernateConfigurationMarker.class }) 
public class CaBridgeDomainServiceConfig {
    @Bean(name= CERTIFICATE_PRODUCT_APP_SERVICE)
    public CertificateProductApplicationServiceCabImpl certificateProductAppService() {
    return new CertificateProductApplicationServiceCabImpl();
    }

    @Bean(name= CERTIFICATE_PROGRAM_APP_SERVICE)
    public CertificateProgramApplicationServiceCabImpl certificateProgramAppService() {
    return new CertificateProgramApplicationServiceCabImpl();
    }
}
```

This code results in spring not finding the implementation classes at all:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'cmb.cabridge.application.cert.CertificateProductApplicationServiceCabImpl' available
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with your first approach. Can you try debugging by printing all your `spring-beans` after the application context gets created to verify what beans are present in the context? See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-show-all-beans

Comment: Yes I have enabled spring framework logging to DEBUG and it shows it finds both beans. I also have printed the ApplicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames() and it also shows both beans.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on github.com?  What spring version are you using?

Comment: Sorry we can't post it on github as its a proprietary application.  Using springframework 5.16.RELEASE.

Comment: Just updated to springframework 5.2.11.RELEASE and spring boot 2.3.6.RELEASE and still having the same problem.

Comment: I discovered that I don't need to have dependencies for both "org.springframework:spring-context:$springFrameworkVersion" and "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:$springBootVersion".  Now I have just the "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:$springBootVersion".  That still results in the same problem.  Also tried spring boot 2.4.0.

Comment: About your second approach with using implementation classes, can you try using the bean name instead of class name to get the bean? `applicationContext().getBean(CaBridgeDomainServiceConfig.CERTIFICATE_PROGRAM_APP_SERVICE);`. Are you using `AOP` in your application?

Comment: I've tried using getBean("beanName") and that behaves similarly and returns the wrong bean.  e.g. getBean("certificateProductAppService") returns the certificateProgramAppService instance.  Not sure what AOP is.

Comment: Maybe your concrete classes are getting proxied if you're using spring aop. Only little can be deduced from whatever code you've posted. Maybe you can post your pom.xml and some more relevant code. Your problem seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/50308666/3503019

Comment: Thank you for the reference to that other post. I have not enabled AOP.  More specifically I am not using any @Aspect or @*Aspect* anywhere in my classes.

Comment: I see. Can you please show your bean impl classes, remove any confidential code? Are you using Transactional annotation on your bean methods? This is  very unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to get things to work using the applicationContext().getBean("beanName", CertificateProductApplicationService.class). The problem was deeper in my code in the CertificateProductApplicationServiceCabImpl class which used and returned the wrong datasource.